# How come the installation process does not ask me for setting my network?

Tags: networking, system-installation

I remember that when setting windows in a brand new computer, the setup process asked me to configure my network (Wi-Fi, etc).

However, in the tutorials about installing Ubuntu, I don't see that.

I am going to install Ubuntu in a brand new computer in a couple of hours and I want to make sure about that.

If packages from the internet are needed, how come Ubuntu does not ask me to configure the network during installation?

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop or something else (eg. a specialist release of Ubuntu such as Ubuntu Core). Most networks have DHCP (*dynamic host configuration protocol*) addresses provided, so if your network has a DHCP server, it will automatically use it (there are differences in networking for server & desktop, and you didn't say which you are planning to install).  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-dhcp

Answer (score 2):

The installer *will* ask you to connect to the internet if you are not connected with a wired connection. In [step 5 from the official Ubuntu installation tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#5-prepare-to-install-ubuntu) we read:

> - If you are not connected to the internet, you will be asked to select a wireless network, if available. We advise you to connect during the installation so we can ensure your machine is up to date

The screen that is asking you to connect to the internet with a Wi-Fi connection is similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately this ideal thing does not happen. My pc does not have ethernet, and the screen asking to configure wifi does not appear. also what is written in the manual does not happen

Comment: since I couldn't download updates while installing, I suppose I should do some `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: @KansaiRobot I think that you should be presented with the wireless configuration screen if your wireless card was detected. Was your card detected before installation? Is it detected afterwards? If it is, then yes, run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade` to install the available updates.